# Where to inject "things"

Tags: angularjs

I have a an app.js files which looks something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [$http]);

app.controller('httpController', function($http) {

      $scope.httpCommand = function ($http) {

          //http stuff in here

      };

  });
});
```

I am confused of where to inject dependencies. For example I need $http. Where would I inject this, in the app, controller, or the function itself?

Comment: You already have an `$http` in the controller scope due to closure.

Comment: In the controller. For more infomation, see [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) in AngularJS docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $http dependency is already declared in your controller constructor.  The angular injector service will then pass you the $http instance.  The preferred way to declare dependencies however is to use the inline array annotation, which will prevent conflicts found when you minify / compress your javascript files.  [Angular documentation here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)  Example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [$http]);

  app.controller('httpController',['$http', function($http) {

      $scope.httpCommand = function () {

          //http stuff in here,
          $http.get("www.someurl.com", function(result) {
              //do something with result
          });
      };
  }]);
});
```

Comment: do I need to include it in my module dependency as well though?

Comment: Is there a good reason in AngularJS to pass on the parameter even though it's already in scope? It seems redundant, but maybe there's a good reason.

Comment: @user2924127 - No, you do not need it in your module registration.  It is part of angular.

Comment: @DaveNewton - No, not in this case.